# How can we remove unused feature in Arduino's standard SD library so we can reduce the sketch size?

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, flash, sketch-size

With the ReadWrite example in Arduino IDE, the sketch size is 10980 bytes (34%) of an Arduino UNO's storage. How can we reduce the sketch size? There isn't any kind of `#define` to turn on/off features in `SD.h`. I only need `read`, `write`, `append` and `seek` features, not anything else.

I have found the [PetitFS](https://github.com/greiman/PetitFS) port for Arduino, but it doesn't support appending to a file. There is also [TinySDLogger](https://github.com/Nick507/TinySDLogger) but I think it's for good for logging rather than normal file writing. I have found [SdFat](https://www.if.ufrj.br/%7Epef/producao_academica/artigos/audiotermometro/audiotermometro-I/bibliotecas/SdFat/) too.

My main work has used `26234+` bytes of flash and I cannot add more 10KB to the sketch!

Comment: the Arduino SD library is an old version of SdFat wrapped in arduino style API

Comment: The linker automatically removes code that is not used, so you do not have to care about that. If the size is this big that means that so much of the code is used. I assume the largest part of the library is the file system support, and that is required regardless of which functions you actually use